# grep multipe wildcards in string

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Say I have a file that contains:

```
Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el6_2.0.1.1_x86_64.rpm
Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el6_2.0.1.1_i686.rpm
Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el7_2.0.1.1_x86_64.rpm
Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el7_2.0.1.1_i686.rpm
```

I want to grep and match lines that only contain 'package', 'el6', and 'x86_64'

How would I go about doing that on a one liner using grep? The line *must* match all three and grep shouldn't care about how many characters are in between.  If there is a better tool for the job, I'm happy to use that instead.

I've tried the following and got no results:

```
grep package*el6*x86_64*
```

Seeing posts and documentation, I understand that * does not mean the same thing as it would in shell.  I'm looking for the equivalent of it to use in regex.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What is the output of the thing you tried?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding a way to insert a wildcard for any number of characters.  Didn't find much googling and reading the man page.

Comment: That's fine. Post your attempts and what went wrong here. You are more likely to get constructive help that way. As it stands, your question shows zero effort on your part.

Comment: @MadPhysicist grep `package*el6*x86_64*` 
Reading through some documentation and posts, I understand that * does not mean the same in regex.  But I don't see anything that I can use to replace it with.

Comment: Please edit your question with this information by clicking the "edit" button immediately under the question.

Comment: Are you having fun bullying me? It's a simple question.

Comment: I am sorry if I come off as an a-hole, but I am really just trying to get you to write a proper question with all the relevant info.

Comment: Question is now updated.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate you doing that. I hope you like my answer.

Comment: MikeD, SO has been successful in large part because of its strict format. The format is designed to be useful not just for the person asking the question but for all future readers with similar questions.  What @MadPhysicist was asking for was just part of getting to that standard format.

Comment: @John1024 thanks for the clarification.  Apologies for getting frustrated.

Comment: @John1024. Thanks for the explanation. I will use somethin like that in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your attempt is very close. `*` in shell glob terms is roughly equivalent to `.*` in regex terms. `.` means "any character" and `*` is means "repeated any number of times (including zero).

Your regex just needs `.` before each `*`. The trailing `*` is not necessary:

```
package.*el6.*x86_64
```

Here is a sample run with your input:

```
grep 'package.*el6.*x86_64' <<< "Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el6_2.0.1.1_x86_64.rpm
Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el6_2.0.1.1_i686.rpm
Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el7_2.0.1.1_x86_64.rpm
Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el7_2.0.1.1_i686.rpm"
```

Prints:

```
Release 2.1 OS: RHEL File: package_el6_2.0.1.1_x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Needs more quotes to prevent any possibility of the shell treating that argument as a glob.

Comment: Specifically, it should be: `grep 'package.*el6.*x86_64'`. Otherwise, the shell can treat the operation as a failure without even running `grep` (if the `failglob` option is set), or replace the expression with a list of filenames in the current directory which match the regex when interpreted as a glob, or delete that argument outright (if the `nullglob` option is set).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. My mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your contribution as well.  I'll be sure to use the quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Not the best solution (in fact ineficient), but really easy to remember: join 3 greps

```
grep "package" | grep "el6" | grep "x86_64"
```

Comment: No, if the order isn't guaranteed just use awk instead of a chain of greps with pipes: `awk '/package/ && /el6/ && /x86_64/' file.txt`

Comment: Oops, you are right, my answer is not exactly what were asking for

Answer (score 0):

If they're guarenteed to be in order, then a simple grep:

```
grep "package.*el6.*x86_64" file.txt
```

would do it.  If the items can be in any order, you can try a pipe:

```
cat file.txt | grep package | grep el6 | grep x86_64
```

will only show lines containing all three, but in any order

Comment: `grep package file.txt | grep el6 | grep x86_64` is an alternative for the last one.

Comment: If the order isn't guaranteed just use awk instead of a chain of greps with pipes: `awk '/package/ && /el6/ && /x86_64/' file.txt`.

Answer (score -3):

You can use egrep

```
egrep 'package|el6|x86_64' name_of_file.txt
```

Comment: This matches either, not all three.

Comment: Are you trying to find files that have all three strings in it? Something like:
grep -l package name_of_file.txt | xargs grep -l e16 | xargs grep -l x86_64   ?

Comment: @connollyc4, reread the question -- it's very explicit that all three strings need to be present.

Comment: Try it. You can use the command in my answer so you don't have to type from scratch